# Computes the Short-time Fourier Transform in swift

Tags: ios, tensorflow, coreml

I have created .mlmodel from [tensorFlow speech audio recognition](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio)
the input shape for this model is `Input shape: (124, 129, 1)` which is a The STFT (tf.signal.stft) splits the signal into windows of time and runs a Fourier transform on each window

I am trying to input audio via AVFoundation for recording or processing and implements an Short-time Fourier Transform(STF)  to display a real-time spectrum and get absolute value of audio buffer and then pass it to coreml model, but in the apple documentation I was only able to find the processing for `FFT`.

is it possible to compute the `Short-time Fourier Transform` in swift or should I need to modify the tensorflow

Comment: "Is it possible..." is not a programming question.

Comment: You use the FFT algorithm to compute the STFT.

Comment: try my librosa port to iOS: https://github.com/dhrebeniuk/RosaKit